# Why is background image not repeating on ^IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass

I've created a transition between sections on my page, I wanted to keep this as structured as possible. Now the problem is that the background image is not repeating on IE9, IE10 and IE11 (tested these)

css of transtition:

```
.transition {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    bottom:-1px;
    background-image: url(../img/transition.svg);
}
```

It does work on safari, chrome, firefox (newer versions)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I had to achieve this previously, I found [this](http://www.kaspertidemann.com/how-to-repeat-a-background-svg-image-in-internet-explorer-10/) post. It states the following:

> For whatever reason, Internet Explorer 10 does not support the
>   repeating of SVG-based background images out of the box.

However it is possible to resolve this:

> We need to make Internet Explorer 10 preserve the aspect ratio by
>   slicing the image accordingly. For this to happen,
>   `preserveAspectRatio="none slice"` should be added to the `<svg>` like so:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 149 50" enable-background="new 0 0 149 50" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none slice">
```

*(This is true of IE 9 and IE 11 also)*

In IE9 (the browser I've been using) this stretches the svg across the length of the screen because the `background-size` width is set to `100%`.

Therefore you'll need to set the `background-size` to the size of the image you wish to be repeated. For example when I was testing, I set my `background-size` to be `40px 50px` this set the svg to a 40px by 50px image and then repeated it across the width and height of the div.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure IE is capable of repeating a svg out of the box. In your SVG, try adding:

```
preserveAspectRatio="none slice"
```

to the `<svg>` tag.